# iPod 5 stuck on voice over and is locked

Tags: ios, voiceover

My iPod 5 is stuck on voice over, but it's also on lock screen. I do not know how to unlock it and get to settings to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use voiceover to tap and enter your passcode or you can connect it to iTunes where you synced the iPhone previously and disable the "assistance" that VoiceOver is "providing"

- [Can I enter my pass code when in voice over mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34695/can-i-enter-my-pass-code-when-in-voice-over-mode)
- [How do i enter my numeric password in iPhone 4 in VoiceOver mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16097/5472)

Depending on whether you have trusted a computer, you might need to learn the basics of voice over or bring your phone to someone that can tap and listen to the audio prompts to get the setting changed or the device paired/trusted to a computer running iTunes.